# JDBC: Is it possible to execute another query on the results of a previous query?

Tags: jdbc

I want to first get some result set (that includes two joins and selection), and then get the maximum value for one of the columns in the result set.
I need both the data in the original results set, and the max. 
Is this possible with JDBC, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is. Should look like this:

```
SELECT MAX(derivedTable.myRow) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.some_id) derivedTable
```

The key is to assign your inner select an alias ("derivedTable" above) and perform another selection on that.

*--- Edit based on comment:*

No, I don't think that's possible. Even without the JDBC layer - say, in a direct SQL console - I don't think there is a way to query data in a result set in any RDBMS I know.

Depending on the speed of your query and the size of the result, either performing a second query or just iterating through the results to find the maximum are your best options.

Comment: In that case I didn't understand what you were after. So you want one query, then get the results, and then get the maximum of one column of that previous query result - the motivation being that you don't want to repeat the first query, as you've already performed it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with standard SQL although it's a bit awkward:

```
SELECT a, b, c, (SELECT MAX(c) FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table_id) max_c
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table_id
```

Comment: thanks, I am aware of that method, but I would like to know whether it's possible to actually pefrom it in JDBC with two consecutive queries so as to not add the redundant column to the results.